# I can't manipulate JSON on Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code in Javascript work:

```
var obj = {
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "BMGB4.SAO",
        "02. open": "4.4600",
        "03. high": "4.6700",
        "04. low": "4.3000",
        "05. price": "4.4800",
        "06. volume": "969900",
        "07. latest trading day": "2020-04-09",
        "08. previous close": "4.4000",
        "09. change": "0.0800",
        "10. change percent": "1.8182%"
    }
};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(myJSON);
myJSON = JSON.parse(myJSON);
console.log(myJSON);
console.log(myJSON["Global Quote"]);
console.log(myJSON["Global Quote"]["05. price"]);
```

However, using Google Sheets the compiler accuses me of an error of: TypeError: Cannot read property '05. price 'of undefined (line 53, file "Code")

What the hell, how can you recognize JSON normally in Javascript and Google Sheets?

// I hid the variable url, but it will be one that returns the same JSON as the javascript code I posted up here.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch (url);
var data = JSON.parse (JSON.stringify (response.getContentText ()));

Here is my code on Google Sheets:
  // We convert it to JSON.
   var myJSON = JSON.stringify (data);
   Logger.log (myJSON);
   myJSON = JSON.parse (myJSON);
   Logger.log (myJSON);
   Logger.log (myJSON ["Global Quote"]);
   Logger.log (myJSON ["Global Quote"]["05. Price"]);
```

Comment: What's with the chain of stringify and parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

> var data = JSON.parse (JSON.stringify (response.getContentText ()));

Stringifying and parsing would result in the same object/string. It's the same as writing

> var data = response.getContentText();

`data` is now `string` type.

The following chain of events result in `myJSON` being a `string` and not a `object`

```
   var myJSON = JSON.stringify (data);// Double stringified
   myJSON = JSON.parse (myJSON);//Single stringified
   Logger.log (myJSON ["Global Quote"]);//undefined
   Logger.log (myJSON ["Global Quote"]["05. Price"]);//error
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property '05. price 'of undefined (line 53, file "Code")

#### Solution:

`parse` it one more time or `parse` it to object directly:

```
const data = response.getContentText(); //string
const yourJSON = JSON.parse(data);//object
console.log (yourJSON ["Global Quote"]);//object
console.log (myJSON ["Global Quote"]["05. Price"]);// no error
```

Comment: 510/5000
In google sheats, you can put this syntax:
myJSON ["Global Price"] ["05. Price"]);
He is not accepting the ["05. Price"] parameter
I had done this previously, it was working with another Json of the same format, but this one ended up not working and the strange thing is that in this one I get from another URL, it comes with exactly the same parameter.
I don't know what happened to him to find this parameter strange, when I changed the URL.
I managed to somehow get around the situation with this code:

Comment: function callApi(url, posicaolinha, posicaocoluna){
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  //Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  
  //Evitamos que aconteça qualquer BUG louco com o JSON vindo da URL, resultara em uma String formatada corretamente.
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getContentText()));
  
  //Convertemos em JSON.
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
  
  //Tentamos converter a String em Objeto.
   myJSON = JSON.parse(myJSON);

Comment: //Nos certificamos de funcionar a conversão de String para Objeto.
  var convertidoEmObjeto = JSON.parse(myJSON);
  var objeto = Object.values(convertidoEmObjeto);
  
   //Acessamos o preço da ação, pelo objeto.
  var valorAtualAcao = objeto[0]["05. price"];
  
  //Convertemos o preço da ação em um Float.
  valorAtualAcao = parseFloat(valorAtualAcao);
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 
 //Linha/Coluna
  sheet.getRange(posicaolinha,posicaocoluna).setValue([valorAtualAcao]); 
  
}

Comment: I had to force the conversion.
There is a bug in the JSON.parse function that was not converting the string to Obj
So I had to call her 2x.

Comment: @Anon As explained in my answer, it's not a bug. you're stringifying it twice... so you had to parse it twice. Do `const data = response.getContentText(); //string
const myJSON = JSON.parse(data);//object
console.log (myJSON ["Global Quote"]);//object
console.log (myJSON ["Global Quote"]["05. Price"]);// no error 
`